# Using AngularJS, what will get updated and what will not?

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS 1.5.0, and notice that `{{ foo() }}` will get updated according to two-way binding, but `{{ bar }}` will not.

So if I have an input text box, and is subject to two-way binding, and I change the number in it, `{{ foo() }}` which uses that number will get updated, while `{{ bar }}` which uses that number but in the controller, will not get updated.

Example at: https://jsfiddle.net/507caoxf/

What is the rule?  (please give a reference)

---

The code is:

```
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrlFoo">


    <input type="text" ng-model="foo[2].abc.haha[3]">

    {{ theMagicNumber() }}

    {{ bar }}


</body>
```

and the JS:

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
.controller("ctrlFoo", function($scope, $interval, $log) {

    console.log("coming into the almighty controller");

    $scope.foo = [1, 3, { abc: { haha: [5,6,7,8,9]}}];

    $scope.theMagicNumber = function() {
        $log.log("the majestic function is invoked at ", new Date);
        $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.foo));
        var n = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]);
        return n * n;
    }

    $scope.bar = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]) * 2;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have `ng-controller="ctrlFoo"` in the view, angular instantiates the `ctrlFoo` controller. So that code is executed:

```
console.log("coming into the almighty controller");

$scope.foo = [1, 3, { abc: { haha: [5,6,7,8,9]}}];

$scope.theMagicNumber = function() {
    $log.log("the majestic function is invoked at ", new Date);
    $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.foo));
    var n = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]);
    return n * n;
}

$scope.bar = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]) * 2;
```

What does this code do?

1. It logs a string to the console
2. It initializes an array and assigns it to `$scope.foo`
3. It creates a function and assigns it to `$scope.theMagicNumber`
4. It computes some value and assigns that value to `$scope.bar`

Now, in the view, you have the following expressions:

```
{{ theMagicNumber() }}

{{ bar }}
```

They both do the same thing: watch the value of the expression between the mustaches, and every time they change, refresh the DOM with their new value.

Evaluating `bar` consists in getting the value of `$scope.bar`. Does the value of `$scope.bar` ever changes? No, because it's computed once, when the controller is instantiated. So, every time the digest is done by angular, the value of `$scope.bar` is evaluated by angular, but sine this value never changes, the DOM is never refreshed.

Evaluating `theMagicNumber()` consists in calling the function `$scope.theMagicNumber()` and use the returned value as the result of the evaluation. So, every time the digest is done by angular, the function is called, and returns a new value. So the DOM is refreshed.

This is basically equivalent to doing the following every time the model changes:

```
console.log($scope.bar);
console.log($scope.theMagicNumber());
```

The first console log will always display the same value: the value of bar when it was computed, at instantiation time. Whereas the second one will always call the function, get a new result and print it.

Comment: How come the digest cycle can "dirty check" the function, but not dirty check the variable?  In a way, can we think of any `$scope.someFunction()` being able to observe on everything, but `$scope.someVariable` cannot?

Comment: It checks both. But the value of bar never changes it. Show me the line of code that assigns a new value to bar? There is a single one, and it's called only once, when the controller ins instanciated. So the value of bar never changes. In JavaScript, if you do `var a =  1; var b = a; a = 2; console.log(b);`, the printed value will be 1, not 2.

Comment: you are saying the dirty checking is done by evaluating everything that is a property of `$scope`?  So if it is a primitive, there is no way it can change... if it is an object (or array object), or function, then it can change, and it will be evaluated again and again until no change happens? (wow, what if the function returns a random number?). By the way I am able to make an object get reflected in `{{ wah }}`, in https://jsfiddle.net/507caoxf/3/ or https://jsfiddle.net/507caoxf/4/

Comment: actually... even if it is primitive, it can change too, as in https://jsfiddle.net/507caoxf/5/ so I suppose it is, as you said, when we see `{{ something }}` or `ng-bind="something"`, it is as if the screen (or Angular) is doing a `console.log(something)` but put that output on the screen (or the DOM)

Comment: *you are saying the dirty checking is done by evaluating everything that is a property of $scope*: no, I didn't say that. I said that having `{{ whatever }}` in the view made angular add a watch to the expression `whatever`. And expressions are always evaluated on the scope. It has nothing to do with primitives vs. not primitives. The expression `bla` is evaluated to *the value of $scope.bla*, whatever `bla` is. The expression `bla()` is evaluated to *the value returned by the call to the function $scope.bla()*. And yes, if bla() returns a random number, you'll have a problem.