# In AngularJS, why does an $interval call trigger the $scope.someFunction() to be called again and again?

Tags: angularjs

This is related to [Using AngularJS, what will get updated and what will not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429891/using-angularjs-what-will-get-updated-and-what-will-not)

So the function `theMagicNumber()` is only called every time the model changes. But if the following lines:

```
    $interval(function() {
        $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.foo));
    }, 1000);
```

is added to the controller, then `theMagicNumber()` is called again and again.  Is that a normal behavior and why is that?

Example at: https://jsfiddle.net/507caoxf/1/

```js
angular.module("myapp", [])
.controller("ctrlFoo", function($scope, $interval, $log) {

    console.log("coming into the almighty controller");

    $scope.foo = [1, 3, { abc: { haha: [5,6,7,8,9]}}];

    $interval(function() {
        $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.foo));
    }, 1000);

    $scope.theMagicNumber = function() {
        $log.log("the majestic function is invoked at ", new Date);
        $log.log(JSON.stringify($scope.foo));
        var n = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]);
        return n * n;
    }

    $scope.bar = +($scope.foo[2].abc.haha[3]) * 2;

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="ctrlFoo">


    <input type="text" ng-model="foo[2].abc.haha[3]">

    {{ theMagicNumber() }}

    {{ bar }}


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal, because, since you trigger a function call every second, and since that function call might change any value in the scope, angular needs to reevaluate the value of the expression `theMagicNumber()`, in order to reflect its potentially new value in the DOM if it has changed.

As I said in your previous question, having `{{ theMagicNumber() }}` in the view makes angular **watch** the value of the expression `theMagicNumber()`. So, every time the digest loop runs (i.e. every second, due to the interval), the expression is reevaluated, and the function is thus called.